# Changing my array definitions to Vectors or Lists?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory

According to that question, I'm more and more worried about the management of the memory in my project, and my program would crash when there is somewhere a conflict in one of the array memories.

The different answers to [this posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188163/memory-allocation-crash) have converged to the fact that I would change my arrays to Vectors and some of my arrays are defined as below:

```
#define Nb 50
int position[Nb];
double indication[Nb];
double sum[Nb];
```

how to change each one of them to

```
 std::vector
 std::list?
```

Can we manipulate / process them when changing their declaration (organizing them in ascending order for example or overwriting one of the values) ?

Comment: `T x[N];` becomes `std::vector<T> x(N);`. Don't use lists.

Comment: See also C++14 [std::dynarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray), if you want a dynamic container whose size is fixed at construction. But the analogue to your example would be `std::array<int, 50>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using fixed size arrays,

```
#define Nb 50
int position[Nb];
```

the modern C++ alternative to these is [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), not `std::vector`:

```
std::array<int, 50> position;
```

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a dynamically sized array, whose size can be determined at runtime *and* can change after construction.

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> v(n); // vector has n value constructed ints
v.push_back(42); // v has n+1 ints now.
```

C++14 offers [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray), which is a dynamically sized array, whose size can be determined at runtime but *cannot* be changed after construction.

Comment: Thank you. And is the manipulation / assignment of values when using that declaration is the same, I mean:
I shall write position[0]=0 and position[2]=4 for example?

Comment: @MelMed yes, it is exactly the same, although the containers also give you iterators, which in this case look quite similar to pointers to elements of a C-style array.

Comment: But it seems for example that the memcopy and the memset don't work on that type. An idea how to do so?

Comment: @MelMed you do not use `memcopy` or `memset`. You don't really need them. If you give examples of what you are trying to do with C arrays, then it would be easier to show the C++ equivalents.

Comment: Yes sure.
I was using memset(position, 0, sizeof(position)); and memcpy(sum_copy, sum, sizeof(sum_copy));

Comment: @MelMed `vector` and `dynarray` will zero-initialize the elements. For `array`, you need to instantiate it like this: `std::array<int, 50> position{};`. As for `memcpy`, all you need is `sum_copy = sum;`

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax is as follows:

```
#define Nb 50
std::vector<int> position(Nb); // create std::vector holding ints, Initial size is 50
```

You should also refrain from using `#define`, but rather use `const`, this is more `C++`:

```
const int Nb = 50; //maybe wrap Nb in a namespace
 std::vector<int> position(Nb);
```

See [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) and its constructors.